# Can the equation rendering delay be increased for editing posts?

Tags: support, feature-request, mathjax, editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Feature request: user script or option to turn off instant MathJax rendering](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/feature-request-user-script-or-option-to-turn-off-instant-mathjax-rendering)

I'm sitting on a very low-end machine here and typesetting a question with equations results in the textbox filling at about 2 chars/second as soon as I enter a first dolar sign. Is there any way to set up a delay of, say three seconds before the equations are re-rendered on *every* newly entered character?

Comment: Oh yes, please! Jack Schmidt's [bookmarklets here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/feature-request-user-script-or-option-to-turn-off-instant-mathjax-rendering) are a good (manual) workaround. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2404/5363) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3221/5363) are two related threads.

Comment: @t.b.: thanks for that link, that helps a lot already. It would probably already help if whatever script currently does the updating only updates iff dolar signs or text between such is modified, but I'm not that much into greasemonkey...

Comment: Retagged it feature-request, since AFAIK there isn't currently a built-in method for achieving what you want.

Comment: @WillieWong agreed, though that basically makes this post a dupe of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2558/163