# Instantaneously Latex Rendering

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, asking-questions

Is it possible to turn off the instantaneous latex rendering when typing up questions on MSE? The instantaneous rendering slows down the process of entering text to an annoyingly slow pace.

Comment: See this question: [Feature request: user script or option to turn off instant MathJax rendering](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2558). The other posts [linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2558) might be of interest, too.